# How to increase the lower bound on possible counter-examples to the Collatz Conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integer-programming

According to Wikipedia, all positive integers up to $2^{60}$ have been tested and follow the Collatz Conjecture. This got me thinking, could one write a program that tests integers of the form $2^{60} +n$? Because obviously, if all integers below $2^{60}$ follow the conjecture, then if repeated iterations of the Collatz function to numbers of the form $2^{60}+n$ yields a number smaller than this bound, then that number automatically must also follow the conjecture, right?

For example, take the number $2^{60} +1$. It is clearly an odd number, so
 $3(2^{60}+1) +1= 3*2^{60}+4$
This number is clearly even, so
$(3*2^{60}+4)/4=3*2^{58}+1$
This number is obviously smaller than $2^{60}$, so therefore $2^{60}+1$ must follow the conjecture! Could one write a program to do this rapidly, increasing this bound?

Comment: But isn't this exactly how they got to 2^60 in the first place?

Comment: Is it? I didn't read very deep in the article. Well its a very sensible method anyway, lol

Comment: Uh, $2^{60}$ is a very large number. Looping over $10^9$ takes about a second, even if you only run a single i++ assembly instruction [Much less iterating Collatz]. So just trying to increase the bound to $2^{61}$ will take another $10^9$ seconds (30 years) if you throw it in a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have observed is that $2^{k}+n$ follows the same path as $n$, at least for a little bit. In fact, $2^{k}+n$ and $n$ take the same patterns of "divide by $2$", "$3n+1$", but with every division you decrease $k$ by $1$. This means that eventually your power of two becomes $1$, and you lose all your predictive power. If this happened sufficiently slowly, it would actually be enough to give a proof by induction of the conjecture! Unfortunately, there are several forms of numbers which will always beat you - On example is $2^{k}-1$. Note that this maps as $2^{k}-1 \to 3\cdot 2^{k}-4 \to 3\cdot 2^{k-1}-1>2^{k}-1$, and this sequence will clearly not decrease until your power of two is exhausted. There are a few other patterns; if you want to explore them, have a look at cycles of negative numbers under the collatz iteration.